# ¿ Como hacer un formulario en php?

Tags: php

Estuve intentando hacer un formulario para hacer una tarea del colegio pero no salió como deseaba y no tengo idea de como corregir mis errores ni que fue lo que hice mal y necesito ayuda.

me queda algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando lleno el formulario me queda así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo mi código para que lo modifiquen y si me pueden decir en que falle y una explicación de como lo hicieron les agradecería muchísimo

```php-html
<?php include("includes/header.php")?>
<?php include("includes/footer.php")?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
<br>
</head>   
 <body>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
         <div class="box">>
            <!--FORMULARIO-->
<FORM action="datos.php"  method="get">
<p>Nombre:<input type="text" name="Nombre"/></p>
<p>Fecha de nacimento:<input type="text" name="Fecha"/></p>
<p>Sexo:<input type="text" name="Sexo"/></p>
<p>Ciudad:<input type="text" name="Ciudad"/></p>
<p>Cedula:<input type="text" name="Cedula"/></p>
<p><input type="Submit" value="Enviar"/></p>
</div>
</nav>
    </FORM>
    </body>
<?php
echo $Nombre = $_GET["Nombre"];
echo $Fecha = $_GET["Fecha"];
echo $Sexo = $_GET["Sexo"];
echo $Ciudad = $_GET["Ciudad"];
echo $Cedula = $_GET["Cedula"];

print "<br><br>";
echo "<h2>Informacion recibida</h2>";
echo "El nombre fue recibido:".$Nombre. "<br>";
echo "La fecha de nacimiento fue recivida:".$Fecha."<br>";
echo "El Sexo fue recibido:".$Sexo. "<br>";
echo "La Ciudad de recidencia fue recibida:".$Ciudad."<br>";
echo "La Cedula fue recibida".$Cedula. "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Hola, puedes por favor decir que problemas tienes en específico?

Comment: lo lamento me aparece este problema Undefined index

Comment: Por favor añadelo pulsando el boton de [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/497917/edit) y pon el texto exacto que te sale de error

Comment: acabo de subir unas fotos con los problemas que da

Comment: Hola, publique una respuesta, dime si es lo que buscabas o si soluciono el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema ocurre cuando cuando imprimes los datos por `GET`, apartir de aquí:

```
echo $Nombre = $_GET["Nombre"];
echo $Fecha = $_GET["Fecha"];
echo $Sexo = $_GET["Sexo"];
echo $Ciudad = $_GET["Ciudad"];
echo $Cedula = $_GET["Cedula"];
```

Ya que cuando abres la página los datos no existen y cuando envias el formulario ya no da error, porque ya se enviaron los datos `GET`, hay varias formas de solucionarlo pero la más facil es comprobar si existen los datos, usando la funcion [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) de php, dejandolo de esta forma:

```
if(isset($_GET))
{
echo $Nombre = $_GET["Nombre"];
echo $Fecha = $_GET["Fecha"];
echo $Sexo = $_GET["Sexo"];
echo $Ciudad = $_GET["Ciudad"];
echo $Cedula = $_GET["Cedula"];
print "<br><br>";
echo "<h2>Informacion recibida</h2>";
echo "El nombre fue recibido:".$Nombre. "<br>";
echo "La fecha de nacimiento fue recivida:".$Fecha."<br>";
echo "El Sexo fue recibido:".$Sexo. "<br>";
echo "La Ciudad de recidencia fue recibida:".$Ciudad."<br>";
echo "La Cedula fue recibida".$Cedula. "<br>";
}
```

Dentro del if puedes poner lo que quieras, o si todavía falla puedes hacerlo así usando la funcion [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php):

```
if(!empty($_GET["Nombre"]))
{
echo $Nombre = $_GET["Nombre"];
echo $Fecha = $_GET["Fecha"];
echo $Sexo = $_GET["Sexo"];
echo $Ciudad = $_GET["Ciudad"];
echo $Cedula = $_GET["Cedula"];
print "<br><br>";
echo "<h2>Informacion recibida</h2>";
echo "El nombre fue recibido:".$Nombre. "<br>";
echo "La fecha de nacimiento fue recivida:".$Fecha."<br>";
echo "El Sexo fue recibido:".$Sexo. "<br>";
echo "La Ciudad de recidencia fue recibida:".$Ciudad."<br>";
echo "La Cedula fue recibida".$Cedula. "<br>";
}
```

Pero principalmente de la primera forma debe de funcionar sin dar errores. Saludos :)

Comment: muchas gracias ya logre solucionarlo te agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0):

No se encuentran definidas porque se utiliza el metodo get

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
     <br>
     </head>   
     <body>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="box">
        <!--FORMULARIO-->
     <form action="datos.php"  method="get">
     <p>Nombre:<input type="text" name="Nombre"/></p>
     <p>Fecha de nacimento:<input type="text" name="Fecha"/></p>
     <p>Sexo:<input type="text" name="Sexo"/></p>
     <p>Ciudad:<input type="text" name="Ciudad"/></p>
     <p>Cedula:<input type="text" name="Cedula"/></p>
     <p><input type="Submit" value="Enviar" name='enviar' /></p>
     </div>
     </nav>
     </form>
     <?php
      //falta el valor name='enviar' lo agregue de ejemplo

     //no estan definidas 
      /*
        print "<br><br>";
        echo "<h2>Informacion recibida</h2>";
        echo "El nombre fue recibido:".$Nombre. "<br>";
        echo "La fecha de nacimiento fue recivida:".$Fecha."<br>";
        echo "El Sexo fue recibido:".$Sexo. "<br>";
        echo "La Ciudad de recidencia fue recibida:".$Ciudad."<br>";
        echo "La Cedula fue recibida".$Cedula. "<br>";
      */  
     ?>
     </body>
```

aparece como undefined variable porque el metodo get te trae los datos de las variables que no han sido  aun recibidas.

Pero al momento de hacer el envio por medio del formulario ya las habra recibido agregue un if y la funcion isset('enviar') para que haci el formulario serciore que efectivamente se recibio el valor del boton 'enviar' una vez que lo comprueba entonces procede a guardar los datos en las variables para posteriormente imprimirlas

```
i <?php
   if(isset($_GET["enviar"])) {

   $Nombre = $_GET["Nombre"];
   $Fecha = $_GET["Fecha"];
   $Sexo = $_GET["Sexo"];
   $Ciudad = $_GET["Ciudad"];
   $Cedula = $_GET["Cedula"];

   //print
   echo $Nombre = $_GET["Nombre"];
   echo $Fecha = $_GET["Fecha"];
   echo $Sexo = $_GET["Sexo"];
   echo $Ciudad = $_GET["Ciudad"];
   echo $Cedula = $_GET["Cedula"];
  }
 ?>
```

El resultado seria dentro del archivo datos.php

juan
111821
male
denver
122343